# Maven Exec Plugin, Spring and ojdbc7 combination prevents JVM from shutting down

Tags: spring, ojdbc, exec-maven-plugin

```
exec-maven-plugin - 1.6.0
Spring - 5.1.5
com.oracle:ojdbc7 - 12.1.0.2
```

I have a simple Java class which initiates a Spring `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` which contains a `DriverManagerDataSource` (oracle database). The class then inserts a few rows before calling the `context.close()` method.

This works great when I run the class from my Intellij. However when I run this via the exec-maven-plugin I get the following error

```
[WARNING] thread Thread[oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser,4,MYCLASS] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 14999msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser,4,MYCLASS] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=MYCLASS,maxpri=10]
```

There are some links on memory leaks around ThreadedCachingBlockSource class but nothing specific on what I have to do.

This only happens when I run via the exec-maven-plugin and NOT when I say right click and run the class in Intellij

I have tried calling explicitly `DriverManager.getDrivers` and `deregisterDriver` that does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging it appears this is nothing to do with ojdbc but everything to do with the exec maven plugin.

As explained in https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/issues/52 adding `-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false` fixed the problem